# How to safely iterate an interlocked slist?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

We have data that is shared between threads stored in a interlocked singly linked list.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684121(v=vs.85).aspx

We know the list does not change after initialization but we would like the various threads to be able to iterate and read the contents of the list.  Is there an safe way to  read/iterate over an slist?

The current code takes the nodes OUT of the list with InterlockedFlushSList, then makes a temp copy of the data and then puts the nodes back into the slist.  If the slist is shared between threads, seems like a race condition just waiting to happen.

Without just going to a different thread safe structure is a there a safe way to read iterate slist?

Comment: SergeyA is right. If the data never changes when you are reading it then you don't need to lock it at all. It's safe to iterate an immutable container from any context while another iteration is occurring.

Comment: Call `RtlFirstEntrySList` to get the first entry, then walk the `SLIST_ENTRY.Next` pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Reading any list is safe in multithreaded enviroment, provided list is not modified when it is read. You do not even need 'interlocked' list for it.

Comment: Good point.  After reviewing the usage in the code I just removed all the interlocked stuff.  It did not matter for our case.  Thanks